# Not able to share URL on Facebook and Twitter using UIActivityViewController in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController for share button.It's showing text and url when I am selecting mail option from list but it's showing only text not url when I am selecting Facebook or Twitter.I searched a lot but not getting solution for my issue.I got one more solution to add "http" in url but is this possible without adding http in url. My code is -

```
 NSArray *activityItems;
NSString *str;
NSString *noteStr;
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.boxscoregames.squares://square?%@",squareID];
noteStr = @"You have been invited to join the Square game, please follow the link below on your iPhone.";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

// str =[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<html><a href=\"%@\">%@</a></html>" ,str,str];
activityItems = @[noteStr,url];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the link is indeed not being shown. But, when you post it, the link will be added to your Facebook/twitter post.

You could of course just also add the link to the text.

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.boxscoregames.squares://square?%@",squareID];
NSString *noteStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have been invited to join the Square game, please follow the link below on your iPhone. %@", link];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[noteStr, url] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for reply..yes, it's working on phone and showing only when i am checking on phone.

Comment: But I want to pass both string as a string and url to redirect on my app.

Comment: The code above will show both the 'note' and the 'link url'. And it will add the link to your post

Comment: Now again my url is changed.No my code is - 


     str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sportssquares://square?%@",squareID];
     noteStr = @"You have been invited to join the Square game, please follow the link below on your iPhone.";
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
     activityItems = @[noteStr,url];


and it is giving me an error of "Cannot post to facebook - connection to facebook failed"